# how do you make a sprite fire an object half of its height

Tags: python, python-3.x, height, pygame, sprite

i am trying to get a sprite to fire half way of up its height and hit an object and end the game using this code but i don't know how to call it up. when i try to make it go half way up its height it says that it is not an integer and i don't know how to make an enemy shoot back.

```
def playerHasHitShoot(playerRect, shootRect):
    if playerRect.colliderect(shootRect):
        return True
    return False

def baddieHasHitShoot(baddieRect, shootRect):
    if baddieRect.colliderect(shootRect):
        return True
    return False

def fire():
    while True:
        shootRect.topleft = ((playerRect / 2), 101)
        shootRect.move_ip(5, 1)
```

Comment: Possibly better suited to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: What if you force integer division with `// 2`? It would probably help to provide the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

`playerRect` is not integer but `Rect` class so you can't divide it.

I thing you mean

```
shootRect.topleft = (playerRect.right + 5, playerRect.centery + 1)
```

(see: [pygame.Rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html))